# Rx Java Android Needs to call multiple api's in a sequence and save each results

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to call multiple Rest Api's in a Sequence and having each Response Dto is different from each other.

Please help me to get rid from this situation that, How can i call these Api's using Rx Java Observables in Android.

Comment: you can use concat operator which takes multiple Observables and concatenates their sequences

Comment: Thanks, This solution is helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same scenario, i use concat operator which takes multiple Observables and concatenates their sequence

If response sequence doesn't require then you can use merge operator also.

[Concat VS Merge operaror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903094/concat-vs-merge-operaror)

Answer (score 1):

no, you should use `map()` or `doOnNext()`, it will look like this

```
Observable.just(1)
    .doOnNext(value -> {
        someRequestX().execute();    
    })
    .map(value -> {
        return nextRequestY().execute();    
    })
    .doOnNext(requestYResponse-> {
        someRequesZ(requestYResponse.someValue).execute();    
    })
    .map(requestYResponse-> {
        return someRequesK(requestYResponse.someValue).execute();    
    })
    .map(requestKResponse -> {
        return someRequesJ(requestKResponse.someValue).execute();    
    })
    .subscribe(requestJResponse -> {
       doSOmethingWithFinalResponse(requestJResponse );
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for network requests is better to use `Single` then `Observable`, because there always will be only one item. To switch from one requests to another, you can use `flatMap`.

Assuming your code is similar, you can try this:

```
class Dto1 {}

class Dto2 {}

class Dto3 {}

public interface Api {

    Single<Dto1> getDto1();

    Single<Dto2> getDto2();

    Single<Dto3> getDto3();
}

private Api api;

public void callApi() {
    api.getDto1()
            .doOnSuccess(dto1 -> {/*do something with dto1*/})
            .flatMap(dto1 -> api.getDto2())
            .doOnSuccess(dto2 -> {/*do something with dto2*/})
            .flatMap(dto2 -> api.getDto3())
            .doOnSuccess(dto3 -> {/*do something with dto3*/})
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `doOnNext()` or `map()` method of Observable and use sync `execute()` of each response and pass them further

Comment: Can you please explain, why not use ```doOnNext()``` or ```map()```? Because i have no further options without ```doOnNext()``` in Retrofit with Rx Java in Android e.g ```api.uploadImage(pref.getAuthToken(), screenshot)``` after that ```execute()``` is not showing in any options after dot operator.

Comment: the answer became rather big for the comment, I gave a full answer in thread