# Operator "concat" does not work properly. Kotlin+RxJava

Tags: kotlin, realm, retrofit2, rx-java2

all! I want to get data in DB at first and than call server if DB is empty. But I don't have any response when I use this way. I tried to call server at first and it was successful. Whats wrong??? This is my code:

```
private fun getDataFromRepository() {
    val subscription =
        carRepository.getCars()!!.
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).
                observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
            subscribe(
            { cars ->
                LOG.info(cars.size.toString())
                    carRepository.saveCarsInDB(cars)
                data.postValue(cars)
            },
            { e ->
                    loadError.postValue(e.toString())
                    LOG.warning(e.toString())
            })
    subscriptions.add(subscription)
}
```

Flowables:

```
fun getCars(): Single<List<Car>>? {
    val db = getDataFromDB()
    val server = getDataFromServerFlowable()
    val mock = getDataFromMock()

    return Flowable.concat(db, server).first(mock)
}

private fun getDataFromServerFlowable(): Flowable<List<Car>> {
    return carApi.getPostsFlowable()
}

private fun getDataFromDB(): Flowable<List<Car>> {
    return RealmCar().queryAllAsFlowable() //"com.github.vicpinm:krealmextensions:2.4.0" 
        .map { cars -> mapper.convertListRealmCarToListCar(cars) }
        .filter { car -> car.isNotEmpty()}
}

private fun getDataFromMock(): List<Car> {
    val cars: MutableList<Car> = mutableListOf()
    val car = Car(0, 0, "Test", "Test", "Test")
    cars.add(car)
    return cars
}
```

Server call:

```
@GET("/photos")
fun getPostsFlowable(): Flowable<List<Car>>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the meaning of `getDataFromRepository` you are not returning anything, just `data.postValue(cars)` (which it's not clear either what you are doing with it)

Comment: This is MVVM pattern. It doesn't matter for this case. Because I want to have cars in this block.

Comment: If the code is not related, please remove it, it makes things harder for the people trying yo help you

Comment: I just generally wouldn't use `com.github.vicpinm:krealmextensions` library, it is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your logic you should consider using `merge` instead of `concat` to interleave the elements. In your case `getDataFromDB()` is not emitting, so the final `Flowable` is waiting for it before emitting `getDataFromServerFlowable()`, There are plenty of good answers of **merge vs concat** (i.e [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38904515/1853785))

Comment: But "merge" is unite data from two Observables. So if two source have data I get much more data than i need.  I want to have only one piece of data.

Comment: then `merge` and then `take(1)`, this way you only get the first one that emitted

Comment: @DenisFedak btw, if both `Flowable` emittted, with `concat` you will have two elements too